# Bootstrap column reordering on at least three screen sizes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with Bootstrap column rendering when I try to specify column reordering for three different screen sizes.

XS devices:

- A
- B
- C
- D

SM and MD devices:

- B A
- D C

LG devices:

- D C B A

I can achieve XS and LG pattern or XS and MD pattern, but unfortunately not all three options at the same time. Is this possible with Bootstrap's classes?

Solution for XS and LG:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-lg-push-9">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Label1</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
             </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-lg-push-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Label2</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Label3</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-9">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Label4</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now when I add middle view classes all get messed up. Is there an option to fix this?

```
<div class="container" style="background-color: pink">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6 col-lg-3 col-lg-push-9 col-lg-pull-0">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Label1</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6  col-lg-3 col-lg-push-3 col-lg-pull-0">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Label2</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6 col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-3 col-lg-pull-0">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Label3</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6  col-md-pull-6 col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-9 col-lg-push-0">
            <p>empty</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The following code is my best try but it simply does not work... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoooray I have found the solution.

First add a simple CSS:

```
.reboot-clearfix {

  @media(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1200px)  {

    .clearfix();
  }
}
```

Second let the code be like this:

```
<div class="container" style="background-color: pink">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6 col-lg-3 col-lg-push-9 col-lg-pull-0">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Label1</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6  col-lg-3 col-lg-push-3 col-lg-pull-0">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Label2</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="reboot-clearfix col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6 col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-3 col-lg-push-0">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Label3</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6  col-md-pull-6 col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-9 col-lg-push-0">
            <p>empty</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The point is: the middle screen needs reset of the floats when "imaginary second line" should begin. This is achieved with CSS and adding the .reboot-clearfix to the first div which must be in second line.

Answer (score 0):

As bootstrap is mobile first, the small view classes will act as a default for the larger views. You only need to add col-sm-6 for the structure to be added to both small and medium classes. to flip the order you want to reverse the push and pull for the small class and cancel them out for the large. You can use jQuery to update the sizes to fit.

**Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/nprtkhh8/1/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="box col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-lg-3 col-lg-push-9">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Label1</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
         </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-lg-3 col-lg-push-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Label2</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 col-sm-push-6 col-lg-pull-3 col-lg-push-0 ">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Label3</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 col-sm-pull-6 col-lg-pull-9">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Label4</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
function resizeOnViewportChange(){

    var heights = $(".box").map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get();

    var  maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);
    var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);

    if (w > 770){
         $(".box").height(maxHeight);
     } else {
         $(".box").height("inherit");
     }
}

resizeOnViewportChange();
$( window ).resize(resizeOnViewportChange)});
```

Comment: It works great for xs and lg devices, but not correct for the sm/md devices. The order of the columns is incorrect. It must be: first row: label2 label1 and second row: label4 label3. Also you have to take different heights of the col- classes into the account.

Comment: Updated to include resizing and flipping the order on the larger views : )